# Relink images in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have created a template in Indesign and it is for a wedding card. My client have 52 colors and he want to show his 52 colors in this template. So document have 52 links. This is for only 1 card type. Client have many cards and I have to relink all 52 images card by card. Linked file name is like this.

Invitation-Layout-005-Aqua-Text, Invitation-Layout-005-Avacado-Text etc…. only different is the color for 52 images. Then next card Invitation-Layout-006-Aqua-Text and Invitation-Layout-006-Avacado-Text etc…. Card number is changing.

So I want to know is there is any easy way to relink these 52 images card by card without manual relink image by image. Please help me.

Comment: What happened to force you relinking them? And are the links in one folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find lots of solutions/scripts for that problem online. See for example [this one](http://kasyan.ho.com.ua/relink.html)

Look for "InDesign relink images script" and you should be on the right trail.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put all linked files in the same directory as indd file. Then every time when you will open indd file, InDesign will try to relink broken links and the first place it looks is in the same directory where the layout file is.